# How to get class name from a static method using reflection

Tags: java, reflection

i'm looking for a way of getting the class name of the class a static method is invoked on.

eg:

```
public  class MySuperClass{
    public static String getClassName(){
        //some trick here...
    }
}
```

and

```
public  class MyInheritingClass extends MySuperClass{
        //some interesting code here...
        public static void main(String [ ] args){
            System.out.println(MyInheritingClass.getClassName());
            //this should output "MyInheritingClass" and NOT "MySuperClass"
        }
    }
```

Any idea of how to work it out?
thanks

Comment: I guess getClassName() should be static...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public  class MyInheritingClass extends MySuperClass{
    //some interesting code here...
    public static void main(String [ ] args){
        System.out.println(MyInheritingClass.getClassName());
        //this should output "MyInheritingClass" and NOT "MySuperClass"
    }
}
```

This a very misleading way of invoking a static method.  It should be illegal.  Static methods are not virtual.  There is absolutely no possible way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: It is a valid way to invoke the method without knowing at compile-time which class finally implements it. If your main-method was in another compilation unit, you can now add a same-named static method in `MyInheritingClass`, and then this is called (without recompiling the main method).  (This is not a way to solve the question, but it has other uses.)

Comment: @Paulo: That's correct; in fact my exercise was trying to prove the opposite!  My initial reaction was similar to when someboy calls a static method from an instance context, but it's a different scenario than that.

Answer (score 1):

> this should output "MyInheritingClass" and NOT "MySuperClass"

Then why not just:

```
MyInheritingClass.class.getSimpleName()
```

?

Comment: Because actually I nead to use this attribute in the superclass, not in the inheriting one =)

Comment: then maybe: this.getClass().getSimpleName() ?

Comment: I cannot reference "this" inside a static scope =)

Comment: No, but why would you want to use this on static scope?
Always call a static method on the class that declares the method.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public  class MySuperClass{
    public  String getClassName(){
        return getClass().getName();
    }
}


public  class MyInheritingClass extends MySuperClass{
    public static void main(String [ ] args){
        System.out.println(new MyInheritingClass().getClassName());
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah...I think that was a typo on the OP's part.  Obviously this it no longer static.

Comment: Yeah, I know this should work...actually i was looking for a "static" solution....but it seems i'm doing something not legal =)

Comment: @ArtoAle: Classes do not inherit static methods/fields so you probably want to do sth illegal.

Comment: Yeah, I realized my fault =) now I'll go for the non-static solution

Answer (score -3):

try this

```
this.getClass().getCanonicalName()
```